# Need help on reading emails with "mail" gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, email

I am doing automation using Watir that creates an email that I need to check. I was pointed at the email gem as being the easiest way to do this.

I added following code and am able to get first email from my inbox.

```
require 'mail' 
require 'openssl'

Mail.defaults do 
  retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "email.someemail.com", 
                          :port       => 995, 
                          :user_name  => 'domain/username', 
                          :password   => 'pwd', 
                          :enable_ssl => true 
end 

puts Mail.first
```

I am new to this forum and have following questions :

1. How can I get all the unread emails? I tried `Mail.all`, `Mail.first`, `Mail.last`, but nothing returns unread email.
2. How can I get all links that are present inside emails? Or mail message body from the specific email? I need to get the email body of first unread email.
3. How can I get emails from a specific folder, if I have subfolders inside my inbox?

Comment: Watir does not have anything to do with your question. I am not sure how this works, but I think you should try to pick the right tags.

Answer (score 14):

Section [6.4.4 of the IMAP protocol](http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/imap4/rfc2060.txt) indicates the different search flags you can use to search for messages.

You can retrieve only new messages by passing the search flags to the find method like so:

```
new_messages = Mail.find(keys: ['NOT','SEEN'])
```

This message was also answered in an [issue on the Mail GitHub repo](https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/258).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you read some of the [documentation](https://github.com/mikel/mail/). Mail.all returns all the emails including read emails. Mail.first returns the first unread. I would imagine doing that again will return the next unread. If your system is controlled, you should not have to worry about so many unread emails. If I were you, I would try it out in IRB until you get a handle on it, maybe even build a class that makes it easier to use for you. Good luck.

Update: The documentation from the Mail gem. If the Mail.first doesn't return an unread email (all the time) then the author should know. You could submit an issue. I don't use that gem myself. I use a gmail gem for testing.

```
Mail.all    #=> Returns an array of all emails
Mail.first  #=> Returns the first unread email
Mail.last   #=> Returns the first unread email
```

Comment: with Mail.First, it always retrive the first email of inbox.  it never retrive first unread email from the mailbox.

Comment: I also want to only get all the unread mails. But I have the same problem: `Mail.all` retrieves all mails, `Mail.first` the first one (regardless whether it is read or not).

Answer (score 0):

how about saving the time when you read mails and then next time when you read all mails process mails only later than that date? i know itz a workaround but i believe it is not supported with the mail gem. Mailman gem does support that but it deletes the mail once you process it.