# How to retrieve only unread emails with ruby mail gem?

Tags: mail-gem

I am trying to retrieve emails with ruby mail gem, in the examples it says that `Mail.last` will retrieve the last unread email https://github.com/mikel/mail#getting-emails-from-a-pop-server but it returns just the last email no matter whether it has been read before or not.
Does anybody know how to get only unread emails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was answered in [Need help on reading emails with "mail" gem in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320596/need-help-on-reading-emails-with-mail-gem-in-ruby)

However the answer was not accepted - don´t know why. Also the question did not mention "unread email" nor the [mail-gem] tag so it was not obvious to search.

The answer points to the solution on the ruby-gem issues report https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/258